# create a shortcode of html form

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to create a short code for html form. because I want   to use this multiple time   in my  word-press page.
I have no idea how to do this . if any help please let help me

```
<form action="<?php echo get_page_link(2599) ?>" method="POST" >
                  <input type='hidden' name='page_id' value='2599'>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-sm-3 col-md-2" id="bgform_text2">
                            <h4>SEARCH</h4>
                            <p>For Your Favourite Place</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-sm-5 col-md-2">
                            <label>Where to ? </label>
                            <input  type="text" name="names" class="input-text full-width" placeholder="start typing here....">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-sm-5 col-md-4">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <label>Arrive </label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <input type="text" name="arive_time" id="departing">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <label>Departs </label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <input type="text" name="depart_time" id="returning">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-sm-9 col-md-2">
                            <label>Sleeps </label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <i class="fa fa-sort"></i>
                                                            <select name="sleeps">
                              <option value="" disabled="" selected=""></option>
                              <option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option></option>
                            </select>

                          </div> 

                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-sm-3 col-md-2">
                            <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit_btn" class="button">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
<?php 

    function my_shortcode(){

        $pagelink = get_page_link(2599);

        return '<form action="'.$pagelink.'" method="POST" >
              <input type="hidden" name="page_id" value="2599">
                <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-sm-3 col-md-2" id="bgform_text2">
                    <h4>SEARCH</h4>
                    <p>For Your Favourite Place</p>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-5 col-md-2">
                    <label>Where to ? </label>
                    <input  type="text" name="names" class="input-text full-width" placeholder="start typing here....">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-5 col-md-4">
                    <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <label>Arrive </label>
                        <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" name="arive_time" id="departing">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <label>Departs </label>
                        <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" name="depart_time" id="returning">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-9 col-md-2">
                    <label>Sleeps </label>
                    <div class="controls">
                    <i class="fa fa-sort"></i>
                                    <select name="sleeps">
                      <option value="" disabled="" selected=""></option>
                      <option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option></option>
                    </select>

                  </div> 

                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-3 col-md-2">
                    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit_btn" class="button">
                </div>
                </div>
            </form>';

     }
    add_shortcode('my_shortcode_name','my_shortcode');
    ?>
```

you can use this shortcode in your page

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[my_shortcode_name]');?>
```

Comment: vel@thanks for support but when I am trying to use this  function its not working . shortcode does not print any thing

Comment: Are you adding this shortcode in text widget or page?

Comment: vel@i m using this in pages

Comment: can you share me screenshot?

Comment: yes @can you check by team viewer , i can share my  id

Comment: vel@let me know  this code nees to inject function.php or any other place

Answer (score 0):

I think you are saying that you do not want to copy-paste the exact same code on multiple places inside your project, [PHP has an include control structure method](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) to take any file and use the contents on run-time.

Your code could eventually look something like this:

```
# form definition inside the main page that needs the form
<form action="<?php echo get_page_link(2599) ?>" method="POST" >
    # include the template
    <?php include('template.php') ?>
</form>

# template.php contains the html form
<input type='hidden' name='page_id' value='2599'>
```